# Unsure about IIS usage of ephemeral ports

Tags: iis, http, port, tcp

There was a discussion at my work today about the usage of ephemeral ports. The discussion was about how a request from a client will hit the server on port 80(this was only a discussion about HTTP requests) but hand it off to a ephemeral port on the server to process the request. I hadn't heard of this before so I was trying to do some research but cant find much documentation indicating this.

Is this really what actually happens? Everything I saw mentions that ephemeral ports are used for clients but the server will still just be port 80. So you should never hit port exhaustion on the server this way, only possibly on the client.

I have seen mention of servers using this approach for FTP(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). Though never anything for HTTP requests.

Any clarification would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TCP socket development, as far as I remember (been a while, may be a bit off), servers have one listener socket call bind, listen and accept and will wait. Once there's an incoming connection, accept will unblock and return another socket object. This 2nd socket object will be like a handle to the actual connection and can perform network I/O while the original socket can loop back to accept network connections. This operation does not use up an ephemeral port.

I'm not sure about the exact inner workings of an OS with regards to connection management, but to me, a network driver could just associate connections from remote ip/port combination to a particular handle ID when accept is called. This allowing a network driver to successfully route network I/O to the correct socket handle while allowing new TCP handshakes from the same local port, but a different remote IP/port to be handled by the listener without really needing an extra port. The listener would once again call accept and create a new socket handle for I/O for the next incoming connection and so on.

Here's a WinSock server socket example: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx).
Here's a description and return value of the accept function: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526(v=vs.85).aspx).